If $\psi(u,v) = (u, u^2 + v^2, v)$ and $\alpha(t)=(ct - b, 5t^2 - ct + c, t + a)$ is a curve with $\alpha$ in $\text{img}(\psi)$, then $a + b + c$ is
If $\psi(u,v) = (u, u^2 + v^2, v)$ with $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\alpha(t) = (ct - b, 5t^2 - ct + c, t + a)$ is a curve with $\alpha \subset \text{img}(\psi)$, then $a + b + c$ is ....
Is anyone aware if I need to apply any parameterization or similar technique to effectively solve this question? 
I've been trying to utilize some properties of the inverse function theorem, but I consistently find myself entangled in a complex system of equations afterward and I'm not so sure if this is the way it can be solved.

You need
$$
(ct-b)^2+(t+a)^2=(c^2+1)t^2+2(a-cb)t+a^2+b^2=5t^2-ct+c
$$
From this
$$
\begin{cases}c^2+1=5\\2(a-cb)=-c\\a^2+b^2=c\end{cases}
$$
From the third equation you have $c \ge 0$. From the first equation you obtain $c=2$ So you have
$$
\begin{cases}2(a-2b)=-2\\a^2+b^2=2\end{cases}
$$
That yields
$$a=1,b=1,c=2$$
and
$$
a=-\frac{7}{5}, b=-\frac{1}{5}, c=2
$$
In the first case we have
$$
a+b+c=4
$$
In the second
$$
a+b+c=\frac{2}{5}
$$
